# Regex for mobile number validation

Tags: regex

In my country (South Africa) mobile numbers have 10 digits and always start with a "0" (e.g. 0821231231).

But they can also have the international dialing code ("+27") replacing the "0" (e.g. +27821231231).

I have this regex:

```
((\+27)|(^(?!\+)(0)))\d{9}
```

Is there any way that this can be improved upon?

Comment: I'm not sure if the negative lookahead (?!\+) is necessary. If the 0 is the very first char then there can't be ANY other char before. And because "any" includes the + I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: Since [tag:regex] dialects vary wildly in syntax and features, regex questions should specify a specific language.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends a bit on what kind of input text you have but if you wanna do exact match per line

```
^(\+27|0)\d{9}$
```

would work well. If you wanna be liberal what comes before and after then

```
.*(\+27|0)\d{9}.*
```

I agree with st88 that negative lookahead makes it confusing. Better to provide your expectation before and after the main pattern (like above)